# C# Copy an object by value

Tags: c#, copy, clone, return-by-value

I have an Object with many properties and i need to create a copy of that object in each iteration such that all properties copied in new born object with their last set value.
(I can't Copy all properties and their values one by one, because my object is actually a custom user control which has many properties and I don't know all of them!)

Comment: What have you tried? Please show object. Why can't copy properties one by one?

Comment: the object actually is my own created user control. I don'n know all properties of the user control!!

Comment: @ReyanChougle, Thanks for your comment, I can not implement a Custom Clone function, because my object is a user control and has lots of Properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension method to copy all object fields and properties.There can be some errors when you try to copy fields and properties,that are reference type.

```
public static T CopyObject<T>(this T obj) where T : new()
        {
            var type = obj.GetType();
            var props = type.GetProperties();
            var fields = type.GetFields();
            var copyObj = new T();
            foreach (var item in props)
            {
                item.SetValue(copyObj, item.GetValue(obj));
            }
            foreach (var item in fields)
            {
                item.SetValue(copyObj, item.GetValue(obj));
            }
            return copyObj;
        }
```